# How can I create a folder on our computer without providing any name to it?

Tags: filesystems

Is it possible to create a folder anywhere on the system with a blank name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not have a folder with no name.  It is not possible.  The name is ***required***.  Without the name a folder cannot exist.

Comment: Sorry, dudes @Matt finally i only find the answer from one of my colleague that if for any folder at any where after removing the text i.e., name from the folder if we press these keys then the folder becomes Name Less. Alt+0160.

Comment: @kalyan That is not nameless.  That is a name of "unicode charcter 160" (it looks like a blank space that takes little room).  You will find that you can only do this once per parent folder.  It is like naming your folder " " (space) but not using space.  I repeat - this is not a nameless folder.

Comment: Thanks for Clearing my Misunderstanding, yes the point that you said is correct in one case, but any how i want a little bit functionality similar to like this which i have said.

Comment: I can't even imagine why you'd want this...

Answer (score 2):

Folders are referenced with their name. Not only must it be of length > 0 it must also be unique in the folder where it is located.

Answer (score 2):

Under some operating systems you can create folders/files that aren't normally visible - not exactly what you asked, but a similar effect.

For example, under Unix/Linux, a file or folder name beginning with a . does not show up in a normal directory listing. Perfectly visible if you use ls -a.

Comment: But, as not fixed to any Programming generally. for ex i have windows xp OS, where i have to create a folder without giving any name to it. But when ever i erase all the name it will show you must provide a name to the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your OS you probably can't directly create a folder with no name, but you might be able to create a folder with a "blank" name. That is to say a name consisting of spaces or, if the OS supports Unicode, other fancy spacing or invisible characters.

But just because your OS doesn't support blank folder names does not mean your filesystem doesn't. Some nasty tools may permit directly altering the filesystem, side stepping the OS. So it's conceivable that you could change the length of an existing folder's name to zero. It's also possible that some filesystems are smart enough to treat this an an error. Anyway you don't really want to do this even if it is technically possible (-: